# quitar hora entre x y z

Tags: python

Hola estoy programando en python una especie de calendario donde se consulta un dia x y si ese dia tiene citas programadas el trae la hora de inicio y la hora de fin para cada cita que haya encontrado

tengo este codigo

```
 horas = [(dt.time(i).strftime("%H:%M")) for i in range(24)]

 horasNoDisponibles = {'cita1': {'horaInicio': '04:00', 'horaFin': '06:00'}, 'cita2': {'horaInicio': '07:00', 'horaFin': '09:00'}}

for i in horasNoDisponibles:
     res = [x for x in horas if (x < horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaInicio"] or x > horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaFin"])]

print(res)
```

me di cuenta que si resta pero solo la ultima cita

asi que las horas de la cita 1 se deben quitar también

lo que intento hacer es que se quiten de la lista [horas] todas las horas que esten entre x y z por ejemplo| inicio = 4:00, fin = 6:00 entonces del calendario se debe quitar 4, 5 y 6

alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Asignas la comprensión de listas a `res` en cada ciclo y por eso únicamente ves los resultados de la comprensión de listas de tu última cita.

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma:

Generamos una lista con todas las horas que abarquen las citas

```
[x for x in horas for i in horasNoDisponibles if (horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaInicio"] <= x <= horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaFin"])]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00']
```

Luego hacemos otra comprensión de listas para devolver las horas que no estén en la lista anterior

```
[x for x in horas if x not in [x for x in horas for i in horasNoDisponibles if (horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaInicio"] <= x <= horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaFin"])]]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00']
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import datetime as dt

horas = [(dt.time(i).strftime("%H:%M")) for i in range(24)]

horasNoDisponibles = {'cita1': {'horaInicio': '04:00', 'horaFin': '06:00'}, 'cita2': {'horaInicio': '07:00', 'horaFin': '09:00'}}

res = [x for x in horas if x not in [x for x in horas for i in horasNoDisponibles if (horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaInicio"] <= x <= horasNoDisponibles[i]["horaFin"])]]

print(res)
```